# Add Api request to button

Tags: c#, api, button, xamarin.forms

I'm very new in C# and Xamarin.Forms but I try to build small app with will shown a weather and that's will be 2 days, I can't get information from weather API(don't know how to join it). I've added to solution dependencies Windows.Csharp and Newtonsoft.Json and nothing works, even from ms.docs app example does not work.I have in my MainPage.xaml.cs i have few buttons:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Apppiii1
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new Page1());

        }

        private async void Button_Clicked_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new Page2());
        }

        private async void Button_Clicked_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new Page3());
        }
        private async void Button_Clicked_3(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new Page4());
        }

        private async void Button_Clicked_4(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new Page5());
        }

        private async void Button_Clicked_5(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new Page6());
        }
    }
}
```

That's my MainPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Apppiii1"
             x:Class="Apppiii1.MainPage">


        <AbsoluteLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Image Source="dark.jpg" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" Aspect="AspectFill"/>


                <StackLayout>
            <Label TextColor="#77d065" HorizontalOptions="Center" FontSize = "25" Text="Meteo plus grand ville en France." />
            <Button Text="Paris" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
            <Button Text="Lyon" Clicked="Button_Clicked_1"/>
            <Button Text="Bordeaux" Clicked="Button_Clicked_2"/>
            <Button Text="Lille" Clicked="Button_Clicked_3"/>
            <Button Text="Nice" Clicked="Button_Clicked_4"/>
            <Button Text="Starsburg" Clicked="Button_Clicked_5"/>
        </StackLayout>

        </AbsoluteLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

and my Page1.xaml.cs

```
    namespace Apppiii1
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
    {
        public Page1 ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
        }

    }
}
```

And Page1.xaml:

```
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Apppiii1.Page1">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Image Source="android1.png"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

And thats a code with I would like to join : on ms site is on 3 parts:
1st

```
    namespace WeatherApp
{
    public class Weather
    {
        // Because labels bind to these values, set them to an empty string to
        // ensure that the label appears on all platforms by default.
        public string Title { get; set; } = " ";
        public string Temperature { get; set; } = " ";
        public string Wind { get; set; } = " ";
        public string Humidity { get; set; } = " ";
        public string Visibility { get; set; } = " ";
        public string Sunrise { get; set; } = " ";
        public string Sunset { get; set; } = " ";
    }
}
```

2nd:

```
    using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace WeatherApp
{
    public class DataService
    {
        public static async Task<dynamic> GetDataFromService(string queryString)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            var response = await client.GetAsync(queryString);

            dynamic data = null;
            if (response != null)
            {
                string json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
            }

            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

3rd:

```
    using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WeatherApp
{
    public class Core
    {
        public static async Task<Weather> GetWeather(string zipCode)
        {
            //Sign up for a free API key at http://openweathermap.org/appid
            string key = "YOUR API KEY HERE";
            string queryString = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip="
                + zipCode + ",us&appid=" + key + "&units=imperial";

            //Make sure developers running this sample replaced the API key
            if (key == "YOUR API KEY HERE")
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("You must obtain an API key from openweathermap.org/appid and save it in the 'key' variable.");
            }

            dynamic results = await DataService.GetDataFromService(queryString).ConfigureAwait(false);

            if (results["weather"] != null)
            {
                Weather weather = new Weather();
                weather.Title = (string)results["name"];
                weather.Temperature = (string)results["main"]["temp"] + " F";
                weather.Wind = (string)results["wind"]["speed"] + " mph";
                weather.Humidity = (string)results["main"]["humidity"] + " %";
                weather.Visibility = (string)results["weather"][0]["main"];

                DateTime time = new System.DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                DateTime sunrise = time.AddSeconds((double)results["sys"]["sunrise"]);
                DateTime sunset = time.AddSeconds((double)results["sys"]["sunset"]);
                weather.Sunrise = sunrise.ToString() + " UTC";
                weather.Sunset = sunset.ToString() + " UTC";
                return weather;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Each time when i click on button I would like to display meteo infos on next page. Please some body help ...

Comment: Xamarin has a complete example that shows how to do this: https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/Weather/

Comment: I know I was looking for already, even that's I have an errors with assembly etc looks like some inside problem I don't undersand why and I want to join it to my buttons if its possible

Comment: even if you can't get it to build, you should be able to examine their code to see how they call the weather service from the UI, and how they handle displaying the results.

Comment: It's my first contact with c# that's why is difficult to understand all those class and conections between

Comment: If you have no experience in C# maybe you should get some. No offence. Creating good apps is difficult as it is, trying to do so without understanding the tools you use must be horrible.

Comment: its a simple app, I need create one for my formation project , and yes it is horrible, im depresst, stuck with it since 4 days now , i dont know how many combination I've been tried ...event I bought some cours on udemy and doe's not work...